# Reverse an arbitrary text in a formula

Tags: formula

I'd like to reverse a text field in a formula:

```
abc -> cba
word -> drow
```

Is there a way to do that for a text of arbitrary length?

Comment: You could use some RIGHT() trickery, but given that you can't loop over a string in a formula field, it may not be very efficient, unless you know the maximum length of the string - just to understand if the formula length will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't accomplish this with formulas, there is no string function that exists which will do this task for you.

What you could do is:
Create a second field on your object, for example: `Palindrome__c`, and fill in the `beforeInsert` and `beforeUpdate` with the reversed value of the field you want.

You can use @Eugene's code for this

Comment: I'm pretty certain that with a max lenghth known of the text being flipped, you could do this in an SF formula.  Pad it with enough spaces to make it a consistent length, make all the references to each character, and trim the result.   Variable length beyond however many references you could make inside a formula, not so much (though Workflow could possibly do it up to 255).  It would be giant and redundant, but do-able, I'm sure.

Comment: the only problem is, that your formula is compiled as well, and you have a maximum of 5000 characters per compiled formula. I'm sure you'll run out of characters before you reach your maximum string length ;)

Comment: When formulas get too long, I move them to Workflows and they are fine (and I even make them much larger).  So my assumption based on experience, not knowing the Field Update limit, is that Field Updates in Workflows would appear to be larger, OR they ignore referenced fields logic contents versus the max size allowable, unlike a Formula.  (shrug)

Comment: You've got me intrigued on what limit I would hit, so I'm going to try this...

Comment: Interesting.  3900 CHARACTERS max (in the editor) in a Field Update.  So my complicated formulas that I've extended via Field updates were below that (but definitely above 5000 "when compiled").  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new feature with Spring 23' release to use the REVERSE() formula in formula fields.

https://theblogreaders.com/spring-23-return-characters-in-a-string-in-reverse-order/

Release Notes: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.salesforce_release_notes.htm&release=242&type=5

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Palindrome {
    public static string reverseString(String source) {
        Integer length = source.length();
        String reverse = '';
        for ( Integer i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- ) 
            reverse = reverse + source.mid(i,1);
        return reverse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are using code, and I specifically asked for a formula field.

Comment: There is a [String method](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm) to do the work for you. Just do `str.reverse()`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something a bit dirty if you know the text will not be too long:

```
mid(FirstName, 10, 1) +  mid(FirstName, 9, 1) +  mid(FirstName, 8, 1) +  
mid(FirstName, 7, 1)  +  mid(FirstName, 6, 1) +  mid(FirstName, 5, 1) +  
mid(FirstName, 4, 1)  +  mid(FirstName, 3, 1) +  mid(FirstName, 2, 1) +  mid(FirstName, 1, 1)
```